# Question about uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\phi$ be a $C^1$ function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\sup_x x^\alpha|\nabla\phi(x)|$ is finite for any multiindex $\alpha$. Is it true that $\phi(\epsilon x)$ converges uniformly to $\phi(0)$ as $\epsilon$ goes to $0$ ?

This was my idea:

$$|\phi(\epsilon x)-\phi(0)|\leq \epsilon |x|\int_0^1|\nabla\phi(\epsilon tx)|dt\leq \epsilon |x| |\nabla\phi(\epsilon Tx)|$$ for some $T\in[0,1]$. The problem is that now
$$\sup_x |\phi(\epsilon x)-\phi(0)|\leq \sup_x \epsilon |x| |\nabla\phi(\epsilon Tx)| = \epsilon \;\sup_y |y/T\epsilon||\nabla\phi(y)|$$ which is just bounded by a constant (without an $\epsilon$ to make it small).

On the other hand I can't find a counterexample.
Thank you.

Comment: By converging to $\phi(0)$ uniformly, do you treat $\phi(0)$ as a constant function on $\mathbb R$? If so, then it is not possible if for example $\phi$ has compact support.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see why

Comment: If $\phi$ is of compact support, then so are all $\phi(\epsilon x)$. Then $\sup_x |\phi(\epsilon x) - \phi(0)|\ge |\phi(0)|$.

Comment: I see, thank you.Let's say that the support of $\phi$ in the unit ball. Then what about $\phi(\epsilon x)-\phi(0)1_{B_\epsilon(0)}$? Does that converge uniformly to zero?

Comment: Yes as the function is continuous at $0$. In this case you dont need all those bounds.

Comment: One last doubt about the initial question. So the convergence is not uniform if the support of $\phi$ is compact. What about if $\phi$ doesn't have compact support. Do we get uniform convergence in this case?